# How to add bootstrap class and condition class in same div?

Tags: reactjs

Following is my code:

```
<div className={temp} 
style={{ padding: "2px", marginBottom: "5px" }}
className="panel panel-default"
>
```

Here how should I add my conditional class and bootstrap class?

Comment: Just like this `<div className={ condition ? "btn btn-danger" : " btn btn-success" }>`

Answer (score 0):

You may separate the classes you wanna apply by spaces in a single string.

Suppose you wanna check for a certain condition, and if that is satisfied, you want to apply the `btn-success` class, else the `btn-danger` class, given that the button will remain small, regardless (having `btn-sm` class always).

```
const temp = someCondition ? "btn btn-sm btn-success" : "btn btn-sm btn-danger";

<div
  className={temp}
  style={{ padding: "2px", marginBottom: "5px" }}
  className="panel panel-default"
>
  text here
</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

With template strings, you can do it like this:

```
className={`panel panel-default ${condition ? temp : ''}`}
```

or without them,

```
className={"panel panel-default " + (condition ? temp : '')}
```